# "Unreachable code detected" , and "name does not exist in the current context" errors

Tags: c#

most of my code seems fine, but when I try to run it, it shows build failed, it shows an issue marks beneath the j in "Console.Write(B[j]);", it shows "Unreachable code detected" over it, it also shows: the name 'j' does not exist in the current context. what is the issue with it?

```
 static void Function(int[]A, int[] B)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < B.Length; j++)
            {
                if (A[i] == B[j])
                {

                    continue;
                }
            } continue;
            Console.Write("the same number in both arrays is:");
            Console.WriteLine(A[i]);

            Console.Write("the location of number in the arrays is:");
            Console.Write(A[i]);
            Console.Write(B[**j**]);
        } 

    }   

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] A = new int[] { 5, 4, 3, 2 };
        int[] B = new int[] { 9, 8, 2, 6 };

        Function(A, B);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the second continue and move Console.Write(B[**j**]); inside second for loop.

Comment: All the `Console.WriteLine` is unreachable due to the `continue` statement above

Comment: what do you mean by " inside second for loop"?

Comment: `j` doesn't exist outside of the scope it was created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your compiler tries to tell you is that the `Console.WriteLine` statements after `continue;` are not reachable.

[`continue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/continue) will jump back to the beginning of the loop and start the next iteration of the loop directly, ignoring all instructions in the loop body that would normally execute after it.

There's a good example of `continue` in the C# Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/continue

From your code i assume you want to find a number that is in both arrays and print it.
If that's what you want to accomplish, you could do it like this:
You can try it in [this dotnet Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1qj7uf)

```cs
public class Program
{
    static void Function(int[]A, int[] B)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < B.Length; j++)
            {
                if (A[i] == B[j])
                {
                    Console.Write("the same number in both arrays is: ");
                    Console.WriteLine(A[i]);

                    Console.Write("the location of number in the arrays is: ");
                    Console.Write($"A[{i}] ");
                    Console.Write($"B[{j}]");
                    return;
                }
            }
        } 

        // could not find two equal numbers
        Console.WriteLine("There are no equal numbers in the array.");
    }   

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] A = new int[] { 5, 4, 3, 2 };
        int[] B = new int[] { 9, 8, 2, 6 };

        Function(A, B);
    }
}
```

This way the loops will run until a match in both arrays is found.

- Once a match is found it will print it to the console.
  The [`return;`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/return) statement causes the function to immediately stop executing and return back to its caller (`Main` in this case)
- In case no match can be found in both arrays, the loops will end and the last `Console.WriteLine` will be called.

Comment: First of all, it works great thanks! and yes it would be helpful if you could explain what exactly is the return; for.